# Is it possible to generate two dimensional Pareto distributed data with python?

Tags: data-analysis, python, data-structure

I would like to generate 2D random data, which is Pareto distributed.

```
a, m = 30., 2. # Shape and mode
s = (np.random.pareto(a,1000) + 1) * m
```

I am using the numpy Pareto package in order to generate the data for X and adding later also (the same way) generated data for Y.

Is that the correct way? Is there another way to generate 2D Pareto Data?

Thank you.

Comment: You can also invert the Pareto cumulative distribution, and then apply it to a random number uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, but what you have is fine (as long as you want $x$ and $y$ to be independent).

Comment: Thank you, @Paul! I want to calculate the causality with this data. But I think it is ok if x and y are independent. But is there a way to generate x and y which are dependent (When I want to compare x1 and y1 with x2 and y2 for example)? Thank you!

Comment: [How general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) do you want that to be?

Comment: Thank you @J.G. I found the implementation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genpareto.html#scipy.stats.genpareto! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With numpy and scipy's random number generation, use a tuple for the `size` parameter to specify the dimensions of a multidimensional array, e.g. `size=(2, 10)` as an argument creates a $2\times10$ two-dimensional array. If you call it `s`, you can set `x, y = s`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. Is it actually the same as generating 2 arrays and putting them together manually or do they have a dependency this way?

Comment: @ネディムSushiDeveloper The way numpy arrays work, it's more efficient to create two variables from an array with two rows than to create them separately, especially if any arithmetic you want to do on them happens before that. Their randomness is independent - in fact, their entire arithmetic is (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944367/are-numpys-basic-operations-vectorized-i-e-do-they-use-simd-operations) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I understand this now much better.